# How can I query for posts that I've marked duplicate

Tags: support, vote-to-close

I need to find a post.  I've tried to search for what I can remember of it and that has failed.  However, I do know that I marked a similar post as duplicate.  Now I'm hoping I can find the duplicate.

How do I search for posts that I've marked as duplicate?

---

There is nothing listed under all actions on my activity page

[image]

---

Neither an exchange nor google search have yielded any useful information

Comment: Suggestions are for edits; closures are under **Votes**. But you can't see them by reason.

Comment: Did you *flag* or *voted to close* the question as a duplicate?

Comment: @Glorfindel I hammered it.

Comment: @piRSquared How did you do it?

Comment: under votes, there is a closures tab  http://stackoverflow.com/users/2336654/pirsquared?tab=votes

Comment: @PraveenKumar [better link](http://stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=votes&sort=closure) (link to your own close votes.)

Comment: @ShadowWizard But those are all not hammered right? Just closure?

Comment: @PraveenKumar my hammers are just one vote closures.  The ones I was looking for were there

Comment: @PraveenKumar yes, but it's easy enough to find if it wasn't long time ago, also there's "[duplicate]" for questions already closed which makes it even easier to search. :)

Comment: Gotcha... There should be a difference to find those are hammered vs close voted.

Comment: @piRSquared Great. But I don't think there's a way to differentiate between hammered vs close voted, right?

Comment: @PraveenKumar not that I know of.

Comment: @piRSquared without visiting the question there's indeed no such way, but what does it matter?

Comment: @ShadowWizard doesn't matter to me. My question was answered